# Removing duplicate rows without one column

Tags: c#, linq

I have DataTable like this:

```
Headache|Nausea|Temp  |Flu
no      |no    |normal|no
yes     |no    |high  |yes
yes     |yes   |high  |yes
yes     |no    |normal|no
no      |no    |high  |no
no      |no    |high  |yes
```

and I want to remove all duplicated rows without one column (Flu):

```
no      |no    |high  |no
no      |no    |high  |yes
```

and get the result:

```
Headache|Nausea|Temp  |Flu
no      |no    |normal|no
yes     |no    |high  |yes
yes     |yes   |high  |yes
yes     |no    |normal|no
```

**How to achieve this using linq ?**

Comment: If you're removing duplicates, why are you removing the originals too?

Comment: This is part of LEM2 algorithm. I must remove those two rows because last column is decision and those two rows is conflicting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Headache", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Nausea", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Temp", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Flu", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] {"no", "no" ,"normal", "no"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] {"yes", "no" ,"high", "yes"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] {"yes", "yes" ,"high", "yes"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] {"yes", "no" ,"normal", "no"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] {"no", "no" ,"high", "no"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new string[] {"no", "no" ,"high", "yes"});

            var dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => new { Headache = x.Field<string>("Headache"), Nausea = x.Field<string>("Nausea"), Temp = x.Field<string>("Temp") }, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

            DataTable dt2 = dict.Where(x => x.Value.Count == 1).SelectMany(y => y.Value).CopyToDataTable();

            //or simply this
            DataTable dt3 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => new { Headache = x.Field<string>("Headache"), Nausea = x.Field<string>("Nausea"), Temp = x.Field<string>("Temp") })
                .Where(x => x.Count() == 1).SelectMany(y => y).CopyToDataTable();

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks you a lot. There is other solution to group by column without typing names. Data may change so i can't rely on column names.

Comment: You can use either name or index number.

Comment: Can I group by all the columns except the last. I ask because I can get a different number of columns.

Comment: You could use : x.Take(x.Count - 1)

Comment: After a long search still does not know how to use this `x.Take(x.Count - 1)`